Most efficient way to use a function repeatedly
The goal is to use a formula, for simplicity given as:
def my_formula(x):
    return x + 5

, in other functions, in a way that doesn't waste computation time by constantly having to reference back to the formula like Case_2 does. Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is the efficiency of Case_1 and the scalability of Case_2.
def Case_1():
    for i in range(10000):
        y = x + 5

def Case_2():
    for i in range(10000):
        y = my_formula()

This is a problem for me because of the size of my project and the large number of iterations that these formula undergo. Ultimately it would be best if I could call the function and have it stay within the memory of the case im running.
I have tried using simpy and lambdifying the formula as
formula = myformula(x)
numeric_formula = sp.lambdify(x, formula)

, hoping this would create some more efficient way of calling the formula, but it was consistently way way slower.
I have also tried calling it as a function input:
def case_3(n, formula=my_formula):
    for x in range(n):
        y = formula(x)
    return 0

Just to quantify things:
Scenario:_____|_Computation_time(s):___
Case_1         0.0035
Case_2         0.0060
Lambdifying    1.2700
Case_3         0.0060


What you're describing here is "common subexpression elimination".  In this SPECIFIC Case_2 example, you could do tempy = my_formula(x) before the loop, then just use the cached value.  But if the value depends on the value of the loop variable, then there's no way to avoid calling the function N times, right?

Thank you! Its always so hard to find what you're looking for when you don't know what it is you don't understand. I'll have a deep dive into subexpression elimination now :D

@TimRoberts "What you're describing here is common subexpression elimination" It's rather loop-invariant code motion.

"best if I could call the function and have it stay within the memory of the case im running"  But that is what is being done? The function is somewhere in memory. Second thing: other languages have things like inline functions and thats what you need. Found some python version, but I am not sure what is its performance or if its working (its very old)

@Olivier is correct.  Look for his term, not mine.

If computations in my_formula are expensive and x repeat themselves a lot -> use lru_cache. This will take care of saving results of the function for a given number of possible x'es

Thank you everyone! Noted on the correct term to look into.

Sometimes - like in this trivial example - vectorizing with numpy is a good option. If my_fomula(x) gets the same x a lot, adding the @cache decorator could help. Otherwise, its the cost of creating the function object in the call. But even something as trivial as x + 5 has a call to the __add__ method. Optimizing just that initial call to my_function is unlikely to have much of an effect.

Python code is a rather high-level language typically interpreted by CPython which is a (slow) interpreter. Interpreters are pretty slow and CPython performs very few optimization. It does not perform any advanced optimizations of expression because Python is a very dynamic language and the interpreter prevent most of dynamic optimizations. You can reduce the overhead of interpreting the code with Cython, but if you use modules like Simpy, it does not solve many other overheads (dynamic object allocation/free, reference counting, type checking, dynamic typing, Simpy function calls, etc.).

PyPy is a tracing JIT which can perform advanced optimization for modules written in pure-Python. It can optimize loop invariant and perform common sub-expression elimination, remove most of the type checking overheads in simple cases, replace ARC with tracing GCs. It can significantly reduce some overheads but not all. It might fit your needs regarding your exact code. The best is just to try it on a real-world code and check the resulting performance. Note PyPy does not support all Python modules (though most of them).

Last but not least, no module can vectorize a CPython function without a JIT. All existing (in-module) Python JITs have either strong limitations (i.e. they do not support general-purpose codes or do not speed them up), or limited performance (small performance boost especially if you call external modules -- where the speed boost is generally either nul or negative). The key for performance in this case is either not to use CPython (hence my above comments about Cython and PyPy), or to adapt your code so to do vectorized operation in the target module (not always possible).

@JérômeRichard would it be fair to say that, while possible to some extent with things like PyPy, optimising in the way im trying to optimise is something best achieved in another anguage such as C or Fortran for optimal results? It sounds like python is just not intended for this purpose.

Yes Python is not really intended for that though PyPy/Cython can help. Technically you can easily write a part in Cython like you do in C but if you can write pure C/Fortran, then I advise to do it performance wise. Cython can help to integrate the C code in Python though it can make some operation more complicated (if even possible). Most things that are done in C are possible in Cython. A Cython code with C types annotation should be close to C in term of speed while it tends to be more convenient to read for Python users. As for PyPy, it generally cannot compete with C in term of speed.

@Aphus take a look at numba package, it might solve your performance problem here. Given your simple example I think it would be best solution, but if the real code is much more complicated it might not be possible to use numba. Note: you will need numba decorator on both my_formula and Case_2 function

@dankal444 The OP apparently uses Simpy which cannot be optimized by Numba (like Pandas or many CPython modules). In fact, Numba cannot even compile a code using Simpy or any similar C module (except mostly Numpy) so even if a code contains few external calls, this is a problem. objmode is supposed to address this problem but it is currently highly experimental and bogus (in complex applications with large Numba codes, it tends to cause random crashes so far).

@JérômeRichard Sympy was just one of the things I tried to speed things up a bit, its not integral to the code. I'm currently implementing the different things people suggested onto my actual code and will post benchmark results when done. Im excited to see whether JIT compilation with PyPy will beat Fortran on this one.

Ok if you do not use any external module other than Numpy, then Numba is a good solution. PyPy cannot be as fast as native languages like Fortran simply because it has to pay the many Python overheads. This include variable-sized integers and dynamic type checking. PyPy's guard can help a lot but conditional are not so cheap. Besides, the memory layout and this tend to prevent SIMD vectorization like this. The benefit of PyPy is its balance between performance and flexibility. Numba code can be close to native speed but it does not support many things including variable-sized integers.

Also one should also keep in mind that all JIT has to compile the code at runtime while native code does not.

In case you were curious of the final result @JérômeRichard , we have pure python running at 19s, pypy at over 2 min and fortran with 0.08s. The reason is the use of the decimal library.

@Aphus The PyPy timings is suspiciously high so maybe there is something going wrong that can be strongly improved (IDK if it supports efficiently the decimal library). The Fortran timings are not surprising. This is frequent to get order of magnitude faster codes for basic numerical operations like this.
